# open a PDF document from local source in html

Tags: php, html, pdf, local

Hi we have a lot of invoices on a local storage.
they invoice number will be readed from a MySQL DB and i generate a link to this invoice.
Problem is that by clicking on  will be opened a new window but with error and PDF will be not loaded or cant be opened withAcrobat Reader.

```
$invDateOrder = intval($invDateYearArray[1]) . "-" . $invDateYearArray[0];
$pathToInvoice = "X:/ALLGEMEIN/PIXI/Rechnungen/" . $invDateOrder . "/" . $invoiceNumber . ".PDF";
$pathToInvoice  = str_replace('/', '\\', $pathToInvoice);
#$pathToInvoice = "file:///".$pathToInvoice;
```

then in html part:

```
<td><a href="file:/<?= $pathToInvoice ?>" target="_blank"><?= $invoiceNumber ?></a></td>
```

or

```
<td><a href="<?= $pathToInvoice ?>" target="_blank"><?= $invoiceNumber ?></a></td>
```

with file:/ is a link not clickable
by 2nd version a new window will be opened with a path but get an error message
 `Firefox does not know how to open this address, because one of the following (x) is not a registered protocol or is not allowed in this context.`
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try some way from these 3 variance

1) `<a href="file:///K:/AmberCRO-SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>`

2) `<a href="AmberCRO-SOP/2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>`

3) `<a href="2011-07-05/SOP-SOP-3.0.pdf">test.pdf</a>`